# How can I prevent Angular app listening to anchor clicks outside the app's scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Question, so.. I have my angular app (1.5.8) which switches between views using the anchor elements (using`/url#/theSection`. Every time it switches views it shows a loader. There are other anchors like `<a href="#">` that is on a much higher level and not "angularized". Every time I click any of the not angularized anchors (`/url#`) it loads the loader because it thinks its switching between views. Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Comment: use `event.preventDefault()` on invalid href's so url hash never changes

Comment: @charlietfl but this are simple html anchor tag, not handling calls by js at the moment. Besides, I think may be the Angular App should be edited? Thanks

Comment: Sounds more like an app design flaw. Why are these anchors not within angular context? Note that angular has `$anchorScroll` service also